# android: opening and hidding data on click

Tags: android, click

I am making an app in which i have to do make the following .I donot know how to do this(On click of oil the following data appears and when we click again the data hides.).Any help will be appreciated.[image: On click of oil the following data appears and when we click again the data hides.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at "ExpandableListView". Expandable lists are used for exactly these purpose.

Comment: http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/

Comment: Thanks Umesh for your help and +1 for help and i have accepted your answere

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set navigation image in expandable list view??